# One click upload button

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html-input

I am looking to create a button which when clicked opens a dialog window where they select an image to upload and then once they select it and press ok within the dialog window the upload begins (upload bar optional :) )

Preferable it would be a jquery plugin that modifys the functionality of the standard html file input... as I have already written the code using one.

Comment: I am really only looking to upload one file so I would prefer the simplest approach possible. So far they have all been a little over kill for my needs. Thanks :)

Comment: I hear you, but I'm afraid there is no simpler way than using a custom uploader. The browser's file upload button can't be activated programmatically for security reasons.

Comment: Can the form be submitted on the file selection dialogue box being closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery plugin [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) will upload with a progress bar, and includes functionality for single or multiple file uploads.

Answer (score 3):

[SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) is able to do that. It is a Flash-based upload component that you can interact with using JavaScript.

[Demo](http://demo.swfupload.org/v250beta3/overlaydemo/index.php)

Answer (score 2):

There are other flash based solutions other than SWFupload. Have a look at [uploadify.com](http://uploadify.com)

This is a jquery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

there is some cheat to do this using jquery and ordinary html. this is what i use in my project to upload one file (limited to one) and just using one button and no plugin whatsoever although it's button needs styling.

HTML code

```
<form method="get" action="somephp.php">
                <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" style="width: 88px; opacity:0.0; filter:alpha(opacity=0); " onchange='uploadChange()'/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" style="margin-left: -88px"/>
            </form>
```

jquery :

```
<script>
    function uploadChange(){
        $('input[type="submit"]').click();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

https://github.com/bencolon/file-uploader

The script *supports* upload of multiple files, but it's an option. While Uploadify and SWFUpload both require Flash to be installed, this plugin if Flash-free. It's probably the most simple approach to your problem. There are smaller plugins available, but they tend not to work nicely across all browsers.